# How does comparator work?

Tags: java, comparator, autoboxing

I thought the `Collections.binarySearch()`would return never return a 0 cause the comparison in the *comparator* is between two Integer which the `==` operation would always been false, but the run results let me down... Can someone help me out?

```
public class ObjectCompare {

    static Comparator<Integer> com = new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
            return i<j?-1:(i==j?0:1);// i thought i==j would never return true                                          
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
         String[] array = {"0","1","2","3","4","5"};
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer k = new Integer(1);
        Integer l = new Integer(1);
        System.out.println(k==l); // this return's false 
        for(String s : array)
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(list,1,com));// this returns 1
    }

}
```

Comment: It should return `false`, it's comparing two different references.

Comment: the binarySearch's result showed it had found the item. so how to explain this ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Its not very clear, but I guess the OP is asking how `binarySearch()` returned `1` when in the `compare()` method `i is not equal to j`. And that is what I've tried to explain in my answer(hopefully!) :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, the question is "why does the `binarySearch` actually find the item in the list, when my comparator compares instances?" Right?

Well, the answer is as simple as that: because actually it compares two identical instances (references). `Integer` class maintains a pool of cached instances for values between -128 and 127 (inclusive). This pool of instances is always used when `valueOf` is called with an argument between these values.

Here you have 2 calls to `valueOf(1)` (more or less explicit) in your code.

One is here: `list.add(Integer.valueOf(s));`. For one iteration through the loop, the call is actually `list.add(Integer.valueOf("1");` Behind the scenes, `valueOf(int)` is called.

And the second is here: `Arrays.binarySearch(array,1,com)`. The boxing operation from the literal `1` to the `Integer` instance is actually performed via an invocation of `valueOf(int)`.

Comment: tks for you reply ~ so , the second autoboxing just take the same instance in the pool of cached ? and this caused i=1,j=1 both autoboxing to one instance ...thereafter the Integer i,Integer j is the same object?

Comment: Exactly. You can easily see what's happening by checking the source code of `Integer`, more specific its `valueOf(int)` method. If you don't have the sources at hand, check it on grepcode: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.valueOf%28int%29. See how the static `IntegerCache` is built and used.

Comment: wonderful ! that's the answer! dived very deep for it bro ~ one more thing . only the "valueOf()" would use the instance in the pool of cach ,and not these ?  Integer k = new Integer(1);Integer l = new Integer(1);        System.out.println(k==l); // this return's false

Comment: By calling the constructor, you create new instances each time. There's no way to reuse instances in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> `System.out.println(k==l);`

This would return false as they are different objects. As known, you need to use `equals()` method to compare the values of two `Integer` objects.

---

> `return i<j?-1:(i==j?0:1);`

This is the return statement of the `compare()` method. *i will not be equal to j unless the same object is present in twice in the list*. Note that the `compare()` method is called by the [`Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method internally. This is not called by the `binarySearch()` method directly.

---

> `System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(list,1,com));`

This returns 1, but the 1 here represents the index at which the search item was found. It would return `3` if your search item was `System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(list,3,com));`. The `1` returned by `binarySearch()` is not from the `compare()` method. The binary search algorithm will internally call the `equals()` method to compare the `Integer` values during the search.

Hence, the `i == j` clause in the `compare()` which you thought would never satisfy, has nothing to do with the actual binary search which is performed on the list of `Integer`s.

From the docs of [`Collections.binarySearch(List, searchItem, comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

> Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. **The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the sort(List, Comparator) method), prior to making this call.**

Comment: tks for you reply , but i has some different idea . The calling of Collections.binarySearch(List) will treat the "list" as a sorted list , and it do call the "compare()" method , i've checked it out in debug mode . what's more , when i,j are numeral equaled. the autoboxing to the Integer Object will be the same (with the same Id num). this confused me a lot .

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
System.out.println(k.equals(l)); // this return's true
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(k==l); // this return's false
```

because == this compare the address of your integer objects not value...

```
 return i<j?-1:((i.equals(j))?0:1);// i thought i==j would return true
```

instead of

```
return i<j?-1:((i==j)?0:1);// i thought i==j would never return true
```

Comment: accutually , return i<j?-1:((i==j)?0:1);// here i==j did return true ...that's why i post this question .

Comment: try to get the value of System.out.println(i<j?-1:((i==j)?0:1)); it give you true

Comment: i know the answer but that weird two Integer Object is same in indenty . finally i found the answer here :http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/what-is-problem-while-using-in.html

Comment: no you use new keyword to define your value and object if you declare like this Integer i1 = 100; and Integer i2 = 100; it would be same reason for that integer literal in java

Comment: i think the cached is playing the black hand , what good does it for ? and the range from -128,127 is really restricted .

Answer (score 1):

[`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is the boxed variant of `int`, i.e. a reference type. You need to use the [`Integer#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to test for equality as `==` will just test if the references are equal:

```
static Comparator<Integer> com = new Comparator<Integer>(){
    public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
        return i < j ? -1 : (i.equals(j) ? 0 : 1);
    }
};
```

**Edit**

Now that I think about it, writing a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is kind of pointless, since [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) already implements [`Comparable<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: i know with Object comparison i should use "equals()" , but that's just bypass the question .

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty to re-shape the program to focus on the question at hand: the i == j in the compare() method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class StackOverflow {

    static Comparator<Integer> com = new Comparator<Integer>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
          int res = 0;
          if(i<j){
            res = -1;
          } else if(i == j ){
            res = 0;
          } else {
            res = 1;
          }
          return res;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(array,1,com));
    }
}
```

If you debug/step through the code you do see that when comparing 1 with 1, the code goes into the res = 0. This is likely to be an autoboxing quirck? Maybe as it has to auto-unbox them for i

Comment: yeah, i could tell res=0 from the result , "==" operation on Object will compare the identities , so how come the Integer i,and Integer j would have the same indentities.

Comment: as mentioned above, values between -127 and 128 are cached and thus use the exact same object. If you put System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(array,new Integer(1),com)); in the code, it will return -2 which shows it was not found.

Comment: yes,that's because the cached pool holds the instance ,and Integer i,j is identical. tks ~!